# Why are the render files ordered wrong?

Tags: rendering

I am rendering a video as png's, because I need transparency, but even though each frame in the folder is called "file001, file002, file003," etc, it orders it as "file358, file 359, file356, file 357, file354"etc, but it only does this in the blender file view and in the video editor. In windows file explorer, it is fine, but when I put it into blender, the frames are not in order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make sure to sort it, by clicking this button on blender's file viewer.
selecting it to Name will sort it by name

[image]